# Bilinear constraints in Pyomo

Tags: gurobi, drake

I am compiling Drake from source to use Gurobi.

I am able to have bilinear non-convex quadratic costs due to it being supported in Gurobi 9.0:
https://www.gurobi.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Gurobi-9.0-Overview-Webinar-Slides-1.pdf

However, I cannot have bilinear constraints, even though it is supposed to be supported.

```
def cross_prod_2d(vec1, vec2):
    a, b, c = vec1[0], 0., vec1[1]

    d, e, f = vec2[0], 0., vec2[1]
    return -(a*f - c*d)

net_torque += cross_prod_2d(lever_arm, signed_contact_force)

net_torque_slack = prog.NewContinuousVariables(1)

prog.AddConstraint(np.asscalar(net_torque_slack) >= net_torque)


ValueError: GurobiSolver is unable to solve because a GenericConstraint was declared but is not supported.
```

Is the binding just not available? Can we make it available?

Comment: This seems to be an issue with Pyomo - added some text that will hopefully get attention of Pyomo experts.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question is about [`pydrake.solvers.GurobiSolver`](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.solvers.html#pydrake.solvers.GurobiSolver), not pyomo.

Comment: It will require some work to support that bilinear constraint through Drake. Unfortunately I probably won't have time to work on it this week.

BTW, from my limited experience playing with the bilinear constraint with Gurobi, it has scalability issue, that doesn't handle many bilinear constraints. I think your problem requires many bilinear product (for all the contact forces). Asking Gurobi to solve this non-convex problem might not be the best solution.